# Cakephp show number of items in page

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I am using cakephp framework . I have 10 items in one page and 5 items in 2nd page. The items are coming dynamically fetched from database. I want to show the number of items in per page

**For Example:**

> 1st page contains 10 items I want output : 1 of 10
>
> 2nd page contains 5 items
>
> I want output : 11 of 15

Can anyone tell me what will i do in coding i am using pagination in that case.

**My code is as follow**:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have mentioned the version you're using.

For CakePHP 3, refer to [Creating a page counter in CakePHP 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-page-counter)

```
echo $this->Paginator->counter('{{start}} of {{end}}');  // 1 of 10 (for page 1)
```

For CakePHP 2, refer to [Creating a page counter in CakePHP 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-page-counter)

```
echo $this->Paginator->counter('{:start} of {:end}');
```

Comment: Thank you so much Object Mnipulator :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the below code:

Setting ‘format’ to range would output like ‘1 - 5 of 15’:

```
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => 'range'
));
```

For more information please visit cakebook Paginator helper
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html